# Azure devops, what is the difference between stakeholder and basic user, and how to chose?

Tags: azure-devops

When you add a user to Azure devops, you have to chose if that user is basic or stakeholder.

There are only three types of user who use devops:

1. developers
2. admins
3. devops

How do you map stakeholder and basic onto these?

One could assume that stakeholder = admin, and basic = developer, but the documentation seems to point to stakeholders having less permissions.

The docs say

> Stakeholders are users with free but limited access to Azure DevOps features and functions. With Stakeholder access, you can add and modify work items, manage build and release pipelines, and view dashboards.

This doesn't really help.  Is a stakeholder a developer?  If not, who are they?  Does stakeholder = Non Technical manager who doesn't use git or know what a pipeline is?  In this case, why do they have access to pipelines, which are highly technical and only touched by senior devops?

Could anyone shed light on these two user types, and how we would know which to choose and when?

Comment: Yes stakeholder has less permissions. A stakeholder is generally the business person that wants to see / manage work items in the project. They aren't actually technical at all. They can also view Wiki's

Comment: Please accept an answer below if it was useful. It doesn't seem like you're in the habit of accepting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are only three types of user who use devops:
>
> developers
>
> admins
>
> devops

.. and stakeholders. People who aren't necessarily technical but have a stake in the project and need to see / create work items, understand project status, see documentation, approve releases.

DevOps is more than just developers developing code.

They have access to approve pipelines. Which makes sense as these would be the decision makers that approve testing and therefore form part of the approval chain for allowing releases.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, a Stakeholder user is not a developer or technical staff, because the Stakeholder user has no access to Azure Repos in the private project. This means the Stakeholder user can't directly access the code repository, also can't push new changes to the repository.

I think, generally the following roles can be Stakeholders:

- Your customer
- Your business manager or related business staff

Normally, these roles mostly manage or care about the Feature Requests, Task assignment, Business Progress, Cost Control, etc.. These need the roles have the access to Azure Boards and Azure Pipelines.

The document indeed does not have a clear explanation about each access level corresponds what specific role in the organization. However, you can open an issue ticket [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues) to try asking the Microsoft Documentation team to update the document with more explanation for each access level.

Answer (score 2):

The difference outline is in here [Stakeholder access quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops).

Just as other answer said, they are non-technical staffs, like management, sprint manager, producer or probably customer. Because they can also **View (kanban) boards, open and edit work items. Add work items to a board**.

Adding a user to a project will initially assign them as stakeholder, if this is your programmer friend, you need to upgrade him in Organization settings > Users.

Although his/her name might be already there, click **Add user** and re add him/her as "basic level". They will be able to access the repo.

[image]